# How can I draw dual (multiple) column (scale) graph in R?

Tags: r, graph

Stackoverflow,

How do I draw a graph like this in `R` package?

[image: http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/wonkblog/files/2013/12/Screen-Shot-2013-12-30-at-9.31.48-PM.png]

At this graph, left column indicates a variable, and the other right column indicates the other variable.

I tried to use `ggplot2` or basic functions but I was not able to find the solution.

I found some solutions from the web, but they are not clear and looks messy.

I want to academic paper quality graphs. Please Help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't waste your time doing this with ggplot2 because Hadley (ggplot2 author) doesn't like this kind of graph (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/tImExPZg61o) a ggplot2 equivalent is achieved through `facet`